# Implementing a calander from Material-UI that uses Hooks in one of my components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and JavaScript in general and trying my hand on a web app. I want to implement a calandar picker I found from Material-UI, https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/usage

In the start guide it uses hooks to make the calendar but it seems like I cant use one within my component.

I tried moving the function out of my class and calling it in the class but I get the same error so guess that's a no can do.

```
class GameList extends Component {
  state = {};

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div id="gameList">
        {BasicDatePicker()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export function BasicDatePicker(){
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        animateYearScrolling
      />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}

export default (GameList);
```

The Error I recieve is the following:
"Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app"

As far as I can see the rule of hook im breaking is that it is being used inside a class but I don't see another way of using the calendar in my component then.

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: @Rastalamm oh my mistake ofcourse, I've added it to the original post thanks.

Comment: You supposed to render the `BasicDatePicker` like this <BasicDatePicker/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of executing BasicDatePicker component like this `BasicDatePicker()`, use JSX tag `<BasicDatePicker />`

```
function BasicDatePicker(){
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        animateYearScrolling
      />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}


class GameList extends Component {
  state = {};

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div id="gameList">
        <BasicDatePicker />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default (GameList);
```

Comment: This Worked! Thank you. Can I ask how calling the function in that way seemed to have made it work? Im guessing there is something im missing.

Comment: @Jahson , well it is standard way for rendering components (class based and functional). I don't really know what is going on "under the hood", but if you want to use hooks it is the only way. Almost every react tutorial (including [official one](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)) use this syntax.